# How to define composite foreign key mapping in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping, composite-key

I have two tables: users and userdetails as follows:

```
package com.example.easynotes.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@IdClass(UserID.class)
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Id
    String name;

    String department;

    //getters and setters

}
```

The userdetails classes will be this:

```
public class UserDetails implements Serializable{

int id;

String name;

String address;

String otherFields;

//getters and setters

}
```

id and name in users is a composite primary and I want the same fields in userdetails to be the foreign key. How can I achieve this in hibernate ?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to put both key in `@Embeddable` to detach compound key thenafter, put it in `User` Entity using `@EmbeddedId` and map both primary key using `Hibernate Relational Mapping`...

There are two option to `Composite Primary Key`:

1. Using `@EmbeddedId`
2. Using `@IdClass()`

Here down is example:

**----------------------------------- Using EmbeddedId -----------------------------------**

Compound primary key:

```
@Embeddable
public class UserIdName implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String name;
    
    // getter and setter
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class USER{
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserIdName id;

    String department;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Userdetail> userdetail;

    // getter and setter
}
```

UserDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Userdetail")
public class Userdetail {

    @Id
    private int detail_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name") })
    private USER user;

    String address;

    String otherFields;

    // getter setter
}
```

**----------------------------------- Using IdClass -----------------------------------**

Compound primary key:

```
public class UserIdName implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String name;
    
    // getter and setter
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@IdClass(UserIdName.class)
public class USER{
    @Id
    int id;

    @Id
    String name;

    String department;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Userdetail> userdetail;

    // getter and setter
}
```

UserDetails:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Userdetail")
public class Userdetail {

    @Id
    private int detail_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name") })
    private USER user;

    String address;

    String otherFields;

    // getter setter
}
```

**-> If you wanna insert both foreign key manually try below code**

Put this code in `UserDetails`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private USER user;

@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name

// don't forget to put getter setter
```

User Table:

[image]

User Detail Table:

[image]

Comment: is there no solution possible through @IdClass ? also this solution of yours will hold the constraint while inserting data ?

Comment: how do I set the id and name in userdetails object ?

Comment: You want to add both foreign key manually?

Comment: You have two option `@IdClass` and `@EmbeddedId` for composite key see above edited answer