# Hibernate: provided id of the wrong type for class

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I got the below exception when trying to save studentId to the STUDENT_ID table. I don't know how to save an entity has a composite primary key by itself.

> org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class StudentIdEntity . Expected: StudentIdEntity , got class java.lang.Long|ConsoleCatcherOutputStream:write

Here down is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_ID")
@IdClass(StudentIdEntity.class)
public class StudentIdEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_1")
    private Long id1;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_2", nullable = false)
    private Long id2;

    public StudentIdEntity() {
    }

    public Long getId1() {
        return id1;
    }

    public void setId1(Long id1) {
        this.id = id1;
    }

    public Long getLocationId2() {
        return id2;
    }

    public void setLocationId2(Long id2) {
        this.id2 = id2;
    }
}

StudentIdEntity studentIdEntity = new StudentIdEntity();
studentIdEntity.setId1(id1);
studentIdEntity.setId2(id2);
studentImplement.save(studentIdEntity);
```

Comment: Yes, can you let me know how pass a correct type? I tried but I cannot

Comment: I got this error
```org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property of @IdClass not found in entity StudentIdEntity: value```

Comment: they have Long data type

Comment: sorry I misinterpreted the question, @Faeemazaz Bhanej has answered it correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You have know about how to composite primary key there are two way to composite primary key using [**`@IdClass()`**](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys) or [**`@EmbeddedId()`**](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys). You have make separate class for composite primary key.

- First you have to make class `StudentId.java` then pass it into `IdClass` annotation.

Here down is code to composite primary key using `IdClass`:

**StudentId.java**

```
public class StudentId implements Serializable {
    private Long id1;
    private Long id2;

    // default constructor

    public StudentId(Long id1, Long id2) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    // equals() and hashCode()
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_ID")
@IdClass(StudentId.class)
public class StudentIdEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_1")
    private Long id1;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_2", nullable = false)
    private Long id2;

    // default constructor, constructer, getter and setter
}

StudentIdEntity studentIdEntity = new StudentIdEntity();
studentIdEntity.setId1(id1);
studentIdEntity.setId2(id2);
studentImplement.save(studentIdEntity);
```

For further information see here [How to define composite foreign key mapping in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735636/how-to-define-composite-foreign-key-mapping-in-hibernate/69736713#69736713)